# Setup method in Moq, ambiguous call

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I'm trying to use Moq to mock the interface:

```
public interface IMatchSetupRepository
{
    IEnumerable<MatchSetup> GetAll();
}
```

and I'm doing:

```
var matchSetupRepository = new Mock<IMatchSetupRepository>();
matchSetupRepository
    .Setup(ms => ms.GetAll())
    .Returns(null);
```

But it doesn't even compile because of the error:

> error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Moq.Language.IReturns<Data.Contract.IMatchSetupRepository,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Model.MatchSetup>>.Returns(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Model.MatchSetup>)'
>   and
>   'Moq.Language.IReturns<Data.Contract.IMatchSetupRepository,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Model.MatchSetup>>.Returns(System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Model.MatchSetup>>)'

I'm using:

> Moq.dll, v4.0.20926

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try the generic version of `Returns`:

```
var matchSetupRepository = new Mock<IMatchSetupRepository>();
matchSetupRepository
    .Setup(ms => ms.GetAll())
    .Returns<IEnumerable<MatchSetup>>(null);
```

or:

```
var matchSetupRepository = new Mock<IMatchSetupRepository>();
matchSetupRepository
    .Setup(ms => ms.GetAll())
    .Returns((IEnumerable<MatchSetup>)null);
```

Instead. Because you're passing the function null (and there are two overloads of `Returns`), the compiler does not know which overload you mean unless you cast the argument to the correct type.

Comment: No problem!--I thought of a (better) way to do it as well, see the update.

Comment: cool! I'm still getting used to moq, I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows it

Comment: My issue was I was trying to return null for my set-up. Casting it first solved it