# Solve ambiguous call with Moq setup for method to first return and the second to throw exception

Tags: c#, moq

Trying to mock calls to this interface (excert thereof) using Moq...

```
Task<T> StoreAsync<T>(
    IAuthUser user,
    T model, 
    IDataModel relative = null,
    IDictionary<string, object> args = null)
    where T : class, IDataModel;
```

I would like one 'setup' for successful calls

```
mockModelService.Setup(s => s.StoreAsync(It.IsAny<IAuthUser>(), It.IsAny<PaymentModel>(), It.IsAny<IDataModel>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, object>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((IAuthUser u, PaymentModel m, IDataModel d, IDictionary<string, object> c) =>
    {
        m.Id++;
        return m;
    });
```

And I aim to have a 'setup' for an override that throws an exception when the model type is specified

```
// Notably the DuplicatePaymentCheck implements a static implicit constructor that takes a PaymentModel as parameter
mockModelService.Setup(s => s.StoreAsync<DuplicatePaymentCheck>(
    It.IsAny<IAuthUser>(), It.IsAny<DuplicatePaymentCheck>(), null, null))
    .ThrowsAsync(
        new ValidationException(40003, "Invalid", "DUPLICATE!"));
```

However, my code doesn't compile because I have an ambiguous call. How can I mock this correctly?

(Btw I checked [the similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461853/setup-method-in-moq-ambiguous-call) and couldn't see the connection to this scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Prakhar Londhe pointed me in the right direction, although it wasn't the full answer. What it did was get me focused on the use of generics in the setup call. I had the generic specified on the service method being mocked, but needed that same generic cited on the appropriate parameter.

The changed (working) code looks like this...

```
mockModelService.Setup(c => c.StoreAsync(
    It.IsAny<IAuthUser>(), It.IsAny<DuplicatePaymentCheck>(), It.IsAny<IDataModel>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, object>>()))
    .ThrowsAsync(
        new ValidationException(40003, "Invalid", "DUPLICATE!"));
```

Answer (score 3):

My best guess would be that

```
It.IsAny<IDataModel>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, object>>()
```

can also be null; hence, Moq won't know which setup to call when both are passed as null. This is considering `DuplicatePaymentCheck` inherits from `PaymentModel`.

Try

```
It.Is<IDataModel>(x => x != null), It.Is<IDictionary<string, object>>(x => x!= null)
```

in the first setup and check if it compiles.

Comment: Thanks Prakhar, your answer pointed me in the right direction. I moved the generic 'citation' from the method being mocked to the IsAny on the PaymentModel argument.